# numpy beginner: writing an array using numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, csv

I have a numpy histogram that I would like to output as a tab-delimited text file. My code is below:

```
targethist = np.histogram(targetlist, bins=ilist)
print targethist
np.savetxt('ChrI_dens.txt',targethist,delimiter='\t')
```

targetlist and ilist are long lists of integers. I get the following output:

> (array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([       1,    10000,    20000,
>   ..., 15060000, 15070000, 15072422])) Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "target_dens_np.py", line 62, in 
>       np.savetxt('ChrI_dens.txt',targethist,delimiter='\t')   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
>   line 979, in savetxt
>       fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline)) TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray

It seems that the histogram array has been created, but I have done something wrong in the np.savetxt() line. I have read the documentation, but don't understand why any of the arguments in this function would be expecting a float. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the second argument to `savetxt` must be "array-like".  Your input is not "array-like".  e.g.

```
print (len(targethist[0]))
print (len(targethist[1]))
```

Notice the lengths aren't the same?  If the lengths were the same, numpy could convert it to a single 2-D array and everything would be fine, but it can't do the conversion so it fails.

This works

```
np.savetxt('stuff.dat',(targethist[0],targethist[1][1:]),delimiter='\t')
```

But I've truncated your data ;).  You'll need to decide what you want to do to work around this one.

I must admit, the error message here is quite cryptic.

Comment: Spot on! This should have occurred to me before I encountered the cryptic error, anyway. As it turns out, I want to truncate the first integer in the longer array, so this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @pandaSeq I have to admit -- based on that traceback I was scratching my head on this one for a few minutes.  Usually when python-numpy questions sit on SO for more than 10 minutes without any answers, you know something funny is going on ;).