# unable to do np.savetxt on save newly appended string column to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array `mfcc` having mfcc values , and is of shape (5911,20).
I have one list `a =[]` which has 5911 labels like `apple` `cow` `dog`.
I want to append the these labels to the `mfcc` numpy array.

**STEP1** 
I converted list with labels to an array :

```
at = np.array(a)
print (at)
print at.shape
print type(at)

['apple' 'apple' 'apple' ..., 'cow' 'cow' 'cow']
(5912,)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**STEP2** I made sure both `at` and `mfcc` were of same dimensions:

```
if len(at) > len(mfcc):
    at= at[ :-1]
```

**STEP3** Then I stacked them together.

```
mfcc_with_labels=np.hstack((mfcc_with_labels,at[:,None]))
print mfcc_with_labels.shape 

(5911,21)
```

**PROBLEM STEP** Now I want to save this `mfcc_with_labels` to a file. So that I can feed it to a neural network later.

```
np.savetxt("mfcc_with_labels.txt", mfcc, newline= "\n", delimiter="/t")
```

and it throws a huge **ERROR**
**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7709c644ca06> in <module>()
      1 print mfcc_features_with_times_and_labels.shape
      2 
----> 3  np.savetxt("mfcc_with_labels.txt", mfcc, newline= "\n", delimiter="/t")
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)
   1256                     raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
   1257                                     "format specifier ('%s')"
-> 1258                                     % (str(X.dtype), format))
   1259         if len(footer) > 0:
   1260             footer = footer.replace('\n', '\n' + comments)
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32') and format specifier ('%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e/t%.18e')
```

**

I tried specifying 'fmt = %s' as an option but nothing happens.

I inspected and 
`mfcc_with_labels[1]` and the stacking/appending did work,

> ['-498.357912575' '-3.40930872496e-14'  '1.55285010312e-14'
>   '-5.31554105812e-14' '4.81736993039e-15'  '-3.17281148841e-14'
>   '5.24276966145e-15' '-3.58849635039e-14'  '3.11248820963e-14'
>   '-6.31521494552e-15' '1.96551267563e-14'  '1.26848188878e-14'
>   '6.53784651891e-14' '-3.15089835366e-14'  '2.84134910594e-14'
>   '1.03625144071e-13' '-5.52444866686e-14'  '-5.04415946628e-14'
>   '1.9026074286e-14' '3.42584334296e-14' 'apple']

Unable to comprehend why it is not being saved.

I already looked at : [numpy beginner: writing an array using numpy.savetxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920318/numpy-beginner-writing-an-array-using-numpy-savetxt) 
[numpy savetxt fails when using file handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273840/numpy-savetxt-fails-when-using-file-handler) 
[How to combine a numpy array and a text column and export to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687990/how-to-combine-a-numpy-array-and-a-text-column-and-export-to-csv)

Please guide me how to save this new numpy array properly. 
I'm from an R programming background, in python is there any easy of python equivalent of saving this array like an R data frame kind of structure?

Final goal is to send this into a neural network.

Comment: `I tried specifying 'fmt = %s' as an option but nothing happens.`  That's awfully vague.  No error message?  No file output?  Are you sure you are looking in the right place for that file?

Comment: I too found that weird , there is no error no warning absolutely nothing. I even tried ` locate mfcc_with_labels` ` from terminal . nothing showed up.
Let me restart my laptop and try again/.

Comment: ok  fmt ='%s' worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `fmt` for `savetxt` is `%.18e`.  Try that with a number

```
In [84]: '%.18e'%12
Out[84]: '1.200000000000000000e+01'
```

The actual format is that string replicated 21 times (the number of columns) and joined with the delimiter.

But your array has a string `dtype`, and contains strings (because you appended the labels.  That doesn't work with that format.

Your `mfcc_with_labels[1]`

```
In [86]:     row = np.array(['-5.04415946628e-14', '1.9026074286e-14', '3.425843
    ...: 34296e-14', 'apple'])
In [87]: row
Out[87]: 
array(['-5.04415946628e-14', '1.9026074286e-14', '3.42584334296e-14',
       'apple'], dtype='<U18')
```

'%s' fmt should work; this formatting does:

```
In [88]: '%s,%s,%s,%s'%tuple(row)
Out[88]: '-5.04415946628e-14,1.9026074286e-14,3.42584334296e-14,apple'
```

Comment: I see the point you are trying to make.  the fmt =`%s` worked. For some reason ubuntu was not able to locate the files. a restart solved the issue.